# How to get the "relation" result from Stanford CoreNLP client in Python?

Tags: python, stanford-nlp

I have trained a new relation extractor model according to
https://nlp.stanford.edu/software/relationExtractor.html and the model works well in Java with the test entry `StanfordCoreNlpDemo`.

However, when I do that in Python env, by adding annotator "relation" in the CoreNLP pipeline, I can't get the "relation" result. I use `stanza` to call corenlp. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I have made it work.
The relation extractor result was not added to pipeline. So i have to do that by myself. But thanks to the corenlp framework, it's affordable to do that